# ng-change not firing when switching between ng-includes

Tags: angularjs

My domain is such that `Bar`s have `Group`s. The following code allows the user to pick a `Bar` (outputted to `{{selected.bar.name}}`). Users are to choose a `Bar`.

If a `Group` only has one `Bar` then the `Bar` is presented at the top level (`step-0`), otherwise the user can drill down into the `Group` and select the `Bar` from there (`step-1`).

In the below code, `Bar 1` and `Bar 2` are their only ones in their group, whilst `Bar 3` and `Bar 4` share a group, `Group 3`.

Everything works well apart from the following sequence:

1. Select `Group 3`
2. Select any `Bar`
3. Click <kbd>Previous</kbd>
4. Select any other `Bar`
5. Selecting `Group 3` again does not take you to `step-1` again; the `ng-change` event is not fired.

```js
(function(ng) {
  'use strict';
  ng.module('awesome', [])
    .controller('BarController', [
      '$scope',
      function($scope) {
        $scope.bars = [{
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Bar 1",
          "group": "Group 1"
        }, {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Bar 2",
          "group": "Group 2"
        }, {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "Bar 3",
          "group": "Group 3"
        }, {
          "id": 4,
          "name": "Bar 4",
          "group": "Group 3"
        }];

        $scope.currentTab = 'step-0';
        $scope.previousTab = null;

        $scope.goBack = function() {
          $scope.currentTab = $scope.previousTab;
          $scope.previousTab = null;
        }

        $scope.groupedBars = _.groupBy($scope.bars, 'group');

        $scope.selected = {}

        $scope.availableGroupedBars = $scope.groupedBars;

        $scope.availableBars = $scope.bars;

        $scope.groupSelected = function(group) {
          console.log('groupSelected');
          $scope.currentTab = 'step-1';
          $scope.previousTab = 'step-0';
          $scope.availableBars = group;
        }
      }
    ]);
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="awesome">
  <div ng-controller="BarController">
    <div ng-include="currentTab"></div>
    Selected bar name: {{selected.bar.name}}
    <button ng-show="previousTab" ng-click="goBack()">Previous</button>
  </div>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="step-0">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="(key, group) in availableGroupedBars">
        <label ng-switch="group.length">
          <span ng-switch-default>{{key}}</span>
          <input ng-switch-default type="radio" name="group" ng-model="selected.group" ng-value="group" ng-change="groupSelected(selected.group)" />

          <span ng-switch-when="1">{{group[0].name}}</span>
          <input ng-switch-when="1" type="radio" name="group" ng-model="selected.bar" ng-value="group[0]" />
        </label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </script>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="step-1">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="bar in availableBars">
        <label>
          {{bar.name}}
          <input type="radio" name="bar" ng-model="selected.bar" ng-value="bar" required />
        </label>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </script>
</div>
```

How can I make the `ng-change` event for `Group 3` fire once returning to `step-0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change event is not fired because nothing changes. You only have one group and that group is still selected when you go back. It stays selected forever, i.e the value of `$scope.selected.group` never changes, regardless of what radio button you choose.

> The ngChange expression is only evaluated when a change in the input value causes a new value to be committed to the model.

I strongly suggest to rethink your approach. If you don't want to then you can add an `ng-change` to your bars in step-0 and clear `$scope.selected.group` whenever a bar is selected.

```
$scope.clearGroup = function() {
  $scope.selected.group = null;
};

<input ng-switch-when="1" type="radio" name="group"
 ng-model="selected.bar" ng-value="group[0]"
 ng-change="clearGroup()" />
```

Comment: Your suggestion works a treat - thanks. In terms of rethinking my approach, could you please suggest something?

Comment: @dav_i The main problem is that on the one hand you mix bars and groups but on the other hand treat them differently. In the end you can only select a bar, can't you? But your UI suggests that you can also select a group.